# Websites stuck in infinite redirect loop after upgrading to iOS 5 (5.0.1)

Tags: iphone, safari, ios

Ever since upgrading my iPhone to iOS 5 (currently at 5.0.1), I've noticed that a few websites that I regularly visit get stuck in a constant redirect loop and never show up.  It's only sites that require logging in as a first step. The two sites that I can think of off the top of my head where this happens are:

- Oreilly Books Online (Safari)
- FT.com

Though I have seen this on more than just these two sites.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Is there anything I can do to try and resolve this on my phone (settings, cache clearing, etc.)?  Or do I have to wait for an OS update or the sites to make a fix?

Also, I'm on the O2 network in the UK, but I can reproduce the behaviour through a VPN and on WiFi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear Safari's cache:

Go to ***Settings App > Safari*** then tap ***Clear History*** and ***Clear Cookies and Data***.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: While this wasn't the root cause, it did uncover the root cause: somehow my "Accept Cookies" setting got set to "Never" after the upgrade. I had an old auth cookie, and the sites kept trying, unsuccessfully, to update it.  Once I cleared that setting, everything worked fine.